# What are the security implications of having your root path seen?

Tags: php

Up until now, I have been storing the root path of my site on my server in an .ini file outside of the public_html directory:

```
[settings]
home_url = 'http://www.example.com'
root_path = '/home/this/that/public_html'
```

And using by:

```
function parse_ini() {

    $root = dirname(__FILE__);
    return parse_ini_file($root.'/../../config.ini', true);

} // End parse_ini

function do_something() {

    $ini = parse_ini(); // I now have $ini['settings']['root_path']

}
```

I feel good about this because the .ini file itself is not publicly accessible, and the only time I parse the file is within a function, so the scope of the data within the file is very limited. This is important as it contains my database credentials.

I am trying to get away from using the .ini file as much as possible, mainly due to the overhead of parsing the file several times per page load (since it's scope is always within a function).

What security implications might I face by putting the root path in a constant with a global scope?

```
define('ROOT_PATH', '/home/this/that/public_html');
```

I'm thinking of having only the database credentials in the .ini file, and moving everything else out of it. The only thing I haven't found a good place for yet is the root path on the server, and I am a little worried about any possible holes this would open up should someone come across it.

Comment: Are you sure the `ini` is not publicly accessible? This should be restricted using an `.htaccess` file, not by hiding it in an unknown place. That would be *security through obscurity*.

Comment: "What are the security implications of having your root path seen?" NONE

Comment: @bytecode77 It is outside of the public_html folder.

Comment: About the overhead of parsing it many times - you might consider storing the parsed contents in a static variable in your `parse_ini()` function and just return the array if it is already populated. If not populated, parse the file, store it in the static variable then return it.  http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php#language.variables.scope.static  Where you call the function, you need not change anything -- only small changes to its definition, and it will only ever read the file once per script.

Comment: The alternative, and likely a better choice for testability is to parse the ini file and pass its array as a parameter to functions that need it rather than calling `parse_ini()` within those functions. That of course requires modifying all those functions to accept it as a parameter and adding it everywhere you call them.

Comment: have youever looked at `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` which is a superglobal variable for the root path, saves you having to mess about saving it in ini files etc....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing's first: Your **ini** file is "not publicly accessible" - Does that mean it can't be easily found because no one knows the directory? If so, that would be [*security through obscurity*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_through_obscurity). Otherwise you can protect it using an `.htaccess` file easily.

If you want to store credentials on the other hand, you should definitely put them in a **PHP** file. This is the canonical way, because there is no way the content of a PHP file can be read, unless you uninstall PHP from your server. It's also parsed more efficiently.

INI files on the other hand could *potentially* be read, if other vulnerabilities are present. **Never poke too many holes into your security, or eventually it's breached!**

**TL;DR:** Exposing the path is **not** a problem. If you rent a cheap webhosting package, you can also see the path, which is no vulnerability to the webhoster, so you can figure out, it's also not one for you!